# Get all data attributes of an element and store them in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I was just playing around with `.dataset` in JavaScript, and from what I see, it returns `DOMStringMap` with only data attributes prefixed with `data-`. Just like so:

```js
console.log(document.body.dataset);
console.log('no ID there ^');
```

```html
<body data-sometag='someValue' id='someID'></body>
```

And here I'm wondering if there is a way to read **ALL** attributes, including the ones like `class` or `src` and store them in JSON.
Just like `.dataset` does, but for all attributes. Is there a standard way to do this, or would I need to create an object first and then work with data attributes individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) to create the object:

```js
var all_attrs = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(document.body.attributes).map((a) => [a.nodeName, a.value]));

console.log(all_attrs);
```

```html
<body data-sometag='someValue' id='someID'></body>
```

For browser that don't support [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var all_attrs = {};

Array.from(document.body.attributes).forEach((a) => {
  all_attrs[a.nodeName] = a.value;
});

console.log(all_attrs);
```

```html
<body data-sometag='someValue' id='someID'></body>
```

Comment: Hmm... I never though you could do this that way. Well... I know How to store the data attributes (in the "ugly" way), but my code usually took much (really much) more space than your approach. Your snippet returns an error but I know what you mean. Could you please fix it, so I can accept a fully working solution?

Comment: From what I see (testing on Windows XP), it doesn't. Returns `TypeError: Object.fromEntires is not a function`. It's probably just the old browser, but I'm not sure. Using Firefox 52 at the moment.

Comment: @FalsePrice What browser+version are you using?

Comment: @FalsePrice You can try the second method (I edited my answer), using `forEach`, as `fromEntries` is not supported on Firefox 52.

Comment: @MrGeek Yeah, `forEach` is more widely supported as it's an older method.